# Tech lead role in a team topologies type of team

Tags: colleagues, work-environment, tech-industry, team-role

In recent years in the country where I am positioned (Scandinavia) the role of the tech lead in a 10 person team has been reduced. More and more teams actually don't have a designated tech lead. The organization where I am positioned has in the recent years been reorganized and at one point the team-lead/tech-lead position was almost eliminated.

Now it seems that they are again positioning some tech leads. I was recently designated as a tech lead. The organization is following team topologies process. I am really struggling with what am I supposed to do as a tech lead. I am already a very senior developer and I have a say in the architecture and all else.

What should be my responsibilities as tech lead?
How to figure them out if the organization up to recently was against such designations and I doubt anyone has any clear idea on what am I supposed to do.

Comment: There is no such thing as "team topologies process". Team Topologies is about recognizing common patterns in types of teams and how these teams interact. Your organization will have to define roles and the responsibilities and accountabilities that come with those roles. The only people who can help with this are your colleagues.

Comment: _"What should be my responsibilities as tech lead?"_ - ask your manager, not to random strangers on internet, we don't know you, and do not work for your organisation, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal answer. Your responsibilities are as assigned by your managers (ask them), or as broad and/or specific as they must be for the project's success.

They may include design, education, negotiation, gathering customer requirements, advising on technology choices, setting priorities, looking ahead to what the next set of requirements or opportunities is likely to be...